# Dunnett's test with unequal variances

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, multiple-comparisons, dunnett

I would like to compare t *treatments* against a single *control* using Dunnett's test. My problem is that the variance is not homogeneous across the treatments.

- Is it a problem for Dunnett's test?
- If so, which method is recommended?
- some R code available?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, unequal variances are not (in and of themselves) a problem.

Ref: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DTK/DTK.pdf